# Include additional font icon into a font-family

Tags: css, fonts

I would like to add the following image...
[image]

in to a font-family that I am using on my website...

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

which does not include this as an icon option.

What is the most effective and efficient process in achieving this?

Comment: Have you looked at [IcoMoon](https://icomoon.io/app)? You can start with Font Awesome (or a subset, which is better for your bandwidth) and add what you like pretty easily. Or you can work with the Font Awesome team to include it; I hear they're pretty responsive.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own icon font-family with [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) using svg vector images. There is a great [tutorial on webdesignerdepot.com](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/01/how-to-make-your-own-icon-webfont/) about this. Don't add icons to an existing font whether that is possible or not, Font Awesome might get updated now and then with new fonts.